# What is a proper way to escape HTML for Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, syntax-error, htmlspecialchars

I'm getting ***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier***
due of the Java-Script clashing syntax or single and double quote.

In the source file,the **$str** is escaped as special chars but not sure why Javascript will hit error.

What is the Correct/Proper way to escape it with single or double quote inside a string for Javascript function use purpose?

Below is my code :

```
<?php
    $str = 'I\'m John Doe < lol > "19" ! ?';
?>
<div onclick="alert('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?>')">Test</div>
<div onclick="alert(&quot;<?php echo htmlspecialchars($str); ?>&quot;)">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to note here is that you don't just have JavaScript. You have JavaScript in an HTML attribute, so you have to escape for JS **then** for HTML.

`json_encode` will escape for JS. It will also add quotes around strings, so do you don't need to do that yourself.

`htmlspecialchars` will escape for HTML.

```
onclick="alert(<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $str ) ); ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you're using strings in the context of JavaScript, use JSON-encoding.  JSON is compatible with JavaScript parsers, and all of the escaping needed will be done for you.

```
var str = <?php json_encode($str) ?>;
```